Partner User unable to set a custom user lookup field
I am facing an issue regarding implemenation of a lookup field being set from the apex class. I am getting error of insufficient access on user record when a partner user triggers the process from an LWC and it tries to create a new record with a lookup to an internal user. OWD for user object is Private.

Partner user logs into community> clicks save> LWC calls apex and apex (with sharing class) tries to save the record along with the field Approver__c that references internal user. It fails.
If the logic to set the field is moved from LWC apex handler to the before trigger that calls a 'with sharing' class and the class sets the field in it, it works.

It looks like the trigger handler class is able to bypass some sharing restriction.
What is the reason for this issue when the field is being set via LWC handler class and it fails?

What's the actual question?  Please edit your question and make it clear what problem you're trying to solve.  It sounds like you already have a solution.

@NickC  - I added the question at the bottom.

I am assuming that your query is - Why the 'with sharing' is respected when the apex is called from LWC, but when same logic is written in the Trigger, the code executes in 'without sharing' context.
The answer to this query lies in the fact that, in term of trigger context, the code executes in 'without sharing' mode
Have a read of this article for better understanding. Under the 'Implementation Details' section there is a point written
Apex triggers can’t have an explicit sharing declaration and run as without sharing.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm
